# How can I remove Styles without changing formatting?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting, styles

How can I remove Styles from all the headings in a Microsoft Word 2013 document, but leave the headings' formatting exactly as they are?

Comment: What version of Microsoft Word are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Word 2013

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible by copy-pasting each element to some application that understands formated text but not styles (an email client would be a good candidate, or a simple-minded editor such as wordpad), remove the style, and then paste the contents back.

For the initial copy, using the style, you can select/copy/paste all elements in one go. The second operation is more labor-intensive.

OTOH, if you tell us why you want to remove the styles, we can possibly explain why you don't need to do so:)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't make it normal, but does remove the headings properties-
Select all instances (manually deselect any you want to keep as headings)
Click create new style (name it temp or old headings etc).  It is applied to your selections.

If you leave it based on heading x it will even change formats when you change the heading format :)

Answer (score 0):

Because Styles are a preset of various format settings, I don't think you can remove them without it changing things.

Style are not "removable" from Word. The only thing you can do is remove Styles from the ribbon.

Unless you have changed it, each new Word document should begin at the default "normal" style.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I had text from a website that I pasted in an existing document, and I didn't want the headers in the text to show up in the table of contents.

My solution was as follows:

- Paste the text in a new file.
- *For each style*, select all text with similar formatting (to the right of the styles dialog)
- Select default style (if you want you can select default style without spacing, as long as it's not a heading that would show up in the table of contents).
- Now *manually* set the style. For a heading you might want to use a bigger font, etc.
- Repeat for every style. This shouldn't be too many (most of the times 5-10 styles in a document is the maximum).

Now you can select all and paste them in the document you want it in.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove all the text with this style. Then the Delete option appear in the Styles.